# Current measurment for a circuit with diode and capacitor in parallel

Tags: diodes, current-measurement, current-source

I have a circuit below.
In this case, the potential difference across the capacitor, Vc, and the potential difference across the the diode(figure2), Vd, would the same, wouldn't they?
So, 
Vd=Vc and
Ic= C*Vd/dt. 
Ip = Id+Ic
Ic = Ir.

Could anyone confirm if this is correct?
 If you don't have the time but it doesn't seem right, even a simple yes or no would help a lot.
(Here, Id = I0(exp(eVd/kT)-1 and Ip is a constant)

[image: Figure1]

Figure1

[image: Figure2]

Figure2

Comment: Ir= Ic-Id+Ip   .....

Comment: Is this a reverse-biased photodiode kind of question?

Comment: That is right. @jonk

Comment: Looked like it. So I gather everything is answered as you were so nice and happy with vofa's help there?

Comment: Yes :-) I should have seen that the current divides, but I don't know why but I get confused over the starting equations. Thanks a lot @jonk.
Thank you for replying so quickly.
Other than vofa's correction, what I have wrote is correct, is it not?

Comment: There's so much more to photodiode detectors (their model is more complex than you show.) And there is a great deal more to using them, as well. A big part of my life was spent making use of them for pyrometry (9 orders of magnitude of current starting at low fA) and phosphor thermometry. So it is hard for me to just say "correct" or otherwise. An answer turns into a book, or something. Also, I don't know what you are up to. So it's hard to say what's important.

Comment: This is just an elementary level of sensor... We just learned to linearize the sensibility of sensors. We are just given simplified models to study. Thanks a lot, again @jonk